# Why is the worst case runtime for delete for a min heap implemented as an array O(N)?

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, heap, binary-heap

I am working on a practice question from  [Practice Data Structures Final](http://courses.cs.washington.edu/courses/cse373/13au/finalSolved.pdf)

**The problem**

Find the worst case asymptotic runtime of delete when using the data structure array kept organized as a min heap.

My initial thought was that the delete operation is *O(log n)* because the algorithm for deletion is

1. Swap the beginning element with the ending element. Set end element as null
2. Decrement Size
3. Percolate the new root down the tree
4. Return the original beginning element

Steps 1, 2, and 4 should all be constant time. Step 3 should run in *O(log n)* because the height of a complete tree is *log n*. So in total, shouldn't the runtime of the deletion be *O(log n)*

However if you look at the answer key(from the link), the worst-case asymptotic running time for deletion when using an array kept organized as a min-heap is *O(n)*. Can someone explain why so?

Comment: You're assuming you know the index of the item to be deleted in the heap. Finding it is O(n).

Comment: By _delete_, do they mean delete _min_ or find and delete _some_ element in the heap?

Comment: But with a heap, shouldn't you only be able to delete the min? Isn't that the whole point?

Comment: Take for example `LinkedList`. It is both a `List` and a `Queue`. It all depends on the API your ADT provides. Your heap might elsewhere be used as a bag or set.

Comment: @Anonymous But deletion itself would be O(log n)?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Oh so because no ADT is provided, It's just a heap, meaning a complete binary tree with a vertical ordering. There is nothing to stop you from removing from the middle of a heap? However if there was an ADT that specified what operations you can perform, say PriorityQueue, there would be that restriction?

Comment: That's my interpretation of _array kept organized as a min-heap_, yes.

Comment: If you're referring to Java's `PriorityQueue`, it does provide a `remove(Object)` method, so no. But yes, your ADT can define what it can and can't do.

Comment: @EJP lookup in a heap should be O(n)  though. You have to look through every node because you don't have that binary search tree property where you can eliminate half the tree after ever iteration.

Comment: I would say several of the answers given are wrong, e.g. this one, and either giving credit for the meaningless O(n+tableSize) *or* deducting 1 point for O(tableSize) (but not both), and not circling delete from heap. The question about delete from heap is just plain ambiguous without specifying whether they mean the min element or an arbitrary element. Very poor quality. And that's just question 1. The constructors in question 2 are all incorrectly written.

Comment: @committedandroider Agreed, I was wrong, fixed it, very good. If you are taking this course for credit I would complain, or shall we say 'seek clarification'.

Comment: In practice and in theory, wouldn't heap still be a complete tree. So you would have the same runtime for delete regardless, even if its the min element or an arbitrary element? It would be the same procedure - finding the node O(n) and bubbling down O(log n).  I agree with your point about deducting 1 point for O(tableSize). I guess they want students to differentiate the chain size and the buckets.

Comment: If you *know* that it's the minimum, e.g. if your ADT only provides that operation, as you suggested above, it is O(log n). The question is ambiguous and needs clarification. Java's PQ is a case in point. It inherits a `remove(Object)` method, as mentioned by @SotiriosDelimanolis, but it won't work if you use it: it will just wreck the heap. The only remove operation that will actually work is removal of the first element.

Comment: Seeing `getMin` in the 'solution' along the time complexity bounds quoted, I wished for `extractMin`.

Comment: @EJP Can you take a look over my answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [Heap Definition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25319305/why-does-a-binary-heap-has-to-be-a-complete-binary-tree) - "A binary tree is only a heap if it has the heap property and is a complete tree"

Thanks to @SotiriosDelimanolis comment, I realized that this problem referred to just an heap, not a heap following a specific ADT(specifies what set of values and operations a data structures supports) like [Priority Queue](http://www.openbookproject.net/thinkcs/archive/java/english/chap16.htm) so it would be possible to remove any value from the Heap.

And thanks to @PaulHankin's comment, I realized that finding a value in a Heap would already run in *O(n)* and shifting the necessary elements around to maintain the complete tree property would also run in *O(n)*. Therefore this remove operation on a heap runs in *O(n)*